# How do I remove the svchost.exe from my PC?

Tags: windows-7, virus, virus-removal, svchost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I am facing problems with my computer because of an `svchost.exe` virus. There are so many `svchost.exe` processes running in my task manager.

Because of this, my computer often slows down. Sometimes when I start my PC, it reboots twice and nothing shows up on my screen. Still the computer and CPU is running.

I have tried to remove it by finding articles on internet and all in vain. What should I do?

Comment: As Nifle said, check our guide there, and if you don't succeed, report back!

Comment: @Himanshu Please edit the question and add hijack this log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Proccess Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and [SVC Host Viewer](http://svchostviewer.codeplex.com/).
Basically SVCHost is a generic name for processes. SVC Host will let you know what runs behind the 'svchost' names, thus you will be able to determine what hogs, slows your PC down.

Answer (score 1):

svchost is not a virus, it's the name of normal vital processes that run in your Windows PC. Granted, they could have a clearer name :)

Comment: Like drwtsn32.exe ? :)